# Why Set-Cookie header not added?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, axios, cross-domain, response

I have a question, I do not understand why the cookie is not added. I have a frontend and backend on separate servers and at various ports, I hit the backend for a token. In response, he gets it, however, it is not set. Could someone look? Secure and httpOnly is deactivated. On the frontend side I have set withCredentials: true.

On the frontend side:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.post('http://backendhost:8584/login', user).then(response => {
            if(response){
                   this.props.history.push('/home');
            }
});
```

Cors On the api side:

```
   @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
                new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
```

Set cookie on the auth server side:

```
    response.addCookie(generateCookie("session-token", customer.getToken()));

    public Cookie generateCookie(String key, String value) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(key,value);
        cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
        cookie.setSecure(false);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(false);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        return cookie;
    }
```

And I get it in chrome:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://frontendhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 16:30:11 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Set-Cookie: session-token=eyJhbGciOiJSUz; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Wed, 16-Jun-2021 16:30:11 GMT; Path=/
transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using so we can help you better

Comment: Sorry, I have already corrected.